# Linq to SQL - How to get total number of results when paging without two queries

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, pagination

I've got the following LINQ query to my IQueryable service

```
Dim eventcount = EventService.QueryEvents().Count
Dim eventlist = EventService.QueryEvents().Skip((page - 1) * 5).Take(5).ToList
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without making two calls to the database?

Comment: I think NHibernate is the only ORM that can do this, with CreateMultiQuery and Future's. Both features not in L2S, EF, LightSpeed. (don't know about SubSonic or any other ORM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider implementing level 2 caching on the count, being careful to get the caching key to contain the relevant criteria, and invalidating it appropriately.

Comment: Read up on ASP.NET caching for application data here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well i was facing the same issue some time back and then i came up with LINQ to SP =).Make and SP and drop that into your entities and use it. you can write Sp according to your need like pulling your records and  total record column too. It is more easy and fast as compare to that whet you are using right now.

I was having the same issue last year and then when it came to performance, then instead of making two queries, I moved to **LINQ to SP**, and made a stored procedure and called it through entities like **LINQ** to stored procedure =). And my stored procedure did all and returned only those records that I wanted and I did paging to at the stored procedure end so that I got limited data at a time rather than all data at application.

You can make and SP and drop that into your entities and use it. you can write Sp according to your need like pulling your records and  total records too as column . Consider having 1000K of records of 100 of tables. Slow performance ?? you can do that by **Linq to SQL** by making a Sp at database level and calling through entities. It will be much faster then the one you trying to achieve =)

Comment: It makes me a little nervous putting one small piece of business logic outside of my business layer. I'll have to think about this one. Thanks

Comment: How expensive is the query that you would want to make it 1 request instead of two, it might just be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: No rock, its all about preformance. imagine if you have 100K of records then it is Best Practice to do that thing at data base level as database knows beter how to do that.And you already said that u have that service then it will not be that big change that calling SP instead of linq quesr =)